# jQuery to remove the first div in a div in a div, only the top div has an id

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I remove the first div in a div in a div?

The HTML structure (not generated by me, so I can't change it) is:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="Label">Label 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Value">
            Value 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="Label">Label 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Value">
            Value 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="Label">Label 3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Value">
            Value 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="Label">Label 4</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Value">
            Value 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want every div that contains the span(class=Label) to be removed, but leaving the div(class=Value)

I tried this:

```
jQuery('#parent div > span.Label').find('div').first().remove();
```

but that didn't work

Thanks for any advice!

Chris

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: `jQuery('#parent div > span.Label').closest('div').remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable by several ways. If you like to traverse from div#parent than try this-

```
$('#parent').children().find('span.Label').parent().remove();
```

Another way is to select the span with class Label then remove it's parent-

```
$('span.Label').parent().remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the top one here, just so I can be sure I'm only removing the label divs from this particular parent.